# What is the fastest way to write hundreds of files to disk using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, memory-mapped-files

My program should write hundreds of files to disk, received by external resources (network)
each file is a simple document that I'm currently store it with the name of GUID in a specific folder but creating hundred files, writing, closing is a lengthy process.

Is there any better way to store these amount of files to disk?
I've come to a solution, but I don't know if it is the best.

First, I create 2 files, one of them is like allocation table and the second one is a huge file storing all the content of my documents. But reading from this file would be a nightmare; maybe a memory-mapped file technique could help. Could working with 30GB or more create a problem?

**Edit:** What is the fastest way to storing 1000 text files on disk ? (write operation performs frequently)

Comment: Please provide more information - what are the normal access patterns to these files? Write once read many? Write many? Are the file sizes expected to change?

Comment: How big are these files typically?

Comment: You cannot speed up disk I/O with code.  Get a faster disk.  Like the ones you'll find in a dbase server.

Comment: Having hundreds of disk drives hooked up to your computer.  :-)

Comment: each file is 5KB average but there are many for example i need to write 1000 file like this. and heavy IO affect other services of my server I want to find a solution to reduce the IO and thus response time of my other services plus (these write operation execute in transaction scope so the overhead is big)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to how [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org) stores its repositories on disk.  Each revision in the repository is stored as a file, and the repository uses a folder for each 1000 revisions.  This seems to perform rather well, except there is a good chance for the files to either become fragmented or be located further apart from each other.  Subversion allows you to pack each 1000 revision folder into a single file (but this works nicely since the revisions are not modified once created.

If you plan on modifying these documents often, you could consider using an embedded database to manage the solid file for you ([Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org) is a good one that doesn't have any size limitations).  This way you don't have to manage the growth and organization of the files yourself (which can get complicated when you start modifying files inside the solid file).  This will also help with the issues of concurrent access (reading / writing) if you use a separate service / process to manage the database and communicate with it.  The new version of Firebird (2.5) supports multiple process access to a database even when using an embedded server.  This way you can have multiple accesses to your file storage without having to run a database server.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is profile your app.  In particular you want to get the counters around Disk Queue Length.  Your queue length [shouldn't be any more than 1.5 to 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175903.aspx) times the number of disk spindles you have.

For example, if you have a single disk system, then the queue length shouldn't go above 2.  If you have a RAID array with 3 disks, it should be more than 6.

Verify that you are indeed write bound.  If so then the best way to speed up performance of doing massive writes is to buy disks with very fast write performance.  Note that most RAID setups will result in decreased performance.

If write performance is critical, then spreading out the storage across multiple drives could work.  Of course, you would have to take this into consideration for any app that that needs to read that information.  And you'll still have to buy fast drives.

Note that not all drives are created equal and some are better suited for high performance than others.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) for that?

I.e. for each received "file", enqueue a write function in a thread pool thread that actually persists the data to a file on disk.

Comment: @Uwe Drives cannot support concurrent write operations, they only have one set of heads. Adding threads is likely to make it perform *worse*.

Comment: So it would be better to enqueue it and use a serialized central thread to write each file a time?

Comment: Yes, it's usually a good idea to queue and so delegate the task to another dedicated thread. If you were to queue it to the threadpool you could encounter a classic problem where you overload the disk and so work items take longer and longer to run. Eventually the threadpool starts to grow the number of threads, which leads to a positive feedback loop and things spiral out of control.

Comment: Side question, just out of curiosity: I'm using SSDs on my PC. Does this apply to SSDs as well or just to mechanical HDDs?

Comment: I know it to be a problem with HDDs, I suspect it would be much less of a problem with faster SSDs, but don't know enough about SSDs to answer really. I suspect that they do not allow concurrent operations either.

Comment: Multi-Thread should be faster when writing to disk. Because of the buffer it has. While the disk is writing, another thread can write to buffer. The amount of threads needs to be calibrated (not a trivial task). But as chibacity said, the best is to have a tread do all the writing job.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: Regardding SSDs, the issue is to do with throughput really as opposed to any physical design of the drive. The CPU only has a single connection to the drive (via the SATA cable) so the maximum disk write speed is constrained at the top end by the size of the SATA pipe or the drive's write speed. Writing on multiple threads just interleaves the data on the SATA connection. On an SSD there would be less waste due to no moving heads, but as you are still just constrained by the throughput you will be better off writing sequentially as that reduces the CPU overhead.

Comment: @Cedrik: I disagree. It doesn't matter if there is a hardware buffer in the disk, the CPU can by far out pace the performance of any disk (even SSDs), so just by running a single thread you can continue to fill the buffer while the disk is writing. Your single thread doesn't block until the buffer is full.